# Xquery: Passing functions as argument

Tags: function-pointers, xquery

I'm working on an xml project in Xquery (using Exist) and I was wondering how I could achieve the following:
I want to create a function evaluate:
evaluate(argument, function)
argument here can be anything and should be compatible with the function.
function is a reference to a function.
some examples:
evaluate(6,nextPrime) -> newtPrime(6) = 7
evaluate("text",toCaps) -> toCaps("text") = TEXT

Is this or something very similar possible in Xquery? And if so, how?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In declarative paradigm, this is called Higher Order Function (HOF) and will be posible in XPath/XSLT/XQuery 3.0 wich is a Working Draft up today. You could use some convention for the currently absent function instance data type, like Dimitre does in his [FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't tell you about exist, but MarkLogic has function pointers:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare function local:upper($str)
{
  fn:upper-case($str)
};

let $function := xdmp:function(xs:QName("local:upper"))
return xdmp:apply($function, "blah")
```

Evaluating this returns BLAH.

Answer (score 1):

dave was right similar support for higher order functions is found in Exist.
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/Higher_Order_Functions
I did not use the exist mechanisms since QName only supports string literals and I could not achieve the dynamic behaviour I needed for my application.
Instead I used this trick:

```
declare function moviestat:call1($name, $param){
    let $query := concat($name, "($param)")
    return util:eval($query)
};
```

note that a generic function for any number of arguments can also be made 
(but was not needed in application)